# Angular Interceptor do not send response header

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, python-django-storages

My GET, POST rquests works fine when there is no set headers in interceptors.
If I do setHeaders in interceptors to set my userId data, 2 things I can see in Network tab:

1. No response headers are seen which was visible earlier
2. CORS error and 'Provisional headers are show' tag in the api request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrwfU.png)

Code (Interceptor)

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // return next.handle(apiRequest);
    
    this.spinnerServcie.requestStarted();

    const user_id = this.loginService.userDetails["user_id"];
    if (!(user_id === undefined || user_id === null || user_id === '')) {
        request = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set( 'userId', user_id.toString())
        });
    }

    return next
    .handle(request)
    .pipe(tap((event) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.spinnerServcie.requestEnded();
        }
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.spinnerServcie.resetSpinner();
        throw error;
    }));
```

It worked fine for GET, but fails for POST. Also I am using HTTPClient only for the request

Comment: Please do not post your code as image since it is harder to reproduce for someone if they have to typed your solution from image instead of just copying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http headers are not for sending data such as `userId`. You must add them in `params` (GET methods) or in `body` (POST methods) to send them to server. see examples below:

GET:

```
this.http.get<MyResponseModel>('https://api.com/my-get-method', {params:{userId: '1'}});
```

POST:

```
this.http.post<MyResponseModel>('https://api.com/my-post-method', {userId: '1'});
```

Or set it in interceptor like this:

```
const constantBodyParams: any = {};
constantBodyParams.userId = 1;
req = req.clone({
  body: {...req.body, ...constantBodyParams}
});
```

Comment: But I want to add it for all request, so I have used interceptor.

Comment: Can I add like this?
request = request.clone({body: {...request.body, userId: user_id.toString()}});

Comment: yeah something like that. I will update the answer. @Charmi